# Code will not run in loop infinitely

Tags: loops, while-loop, autoit

I am having issues having my code loop.  It just runs then ends.  I can compile it, and when I do it runs then ends right away never looping.

What I trying to do is have this code look for a `.bmp`, then if found click on a different `.bmp`, so it needs to be scanning for the `.bmp` all the time.

Here is the code:

```
#include <ImageSearch.au3>

HotKeySet ("S" , "Start")

$x = 0
$y = 0
$heal = 0
$mp = 0
$poth = 0
$potm = 0
$allon = 1


Func Start()
While 1
   $Search = _ImageSearch('healthlow.bmp' , 0)
   If $Search = 1 Then
      $SearchPoth = _ImageSearch('poth.bmp' , 0, $x, $y, 0)
      If $SearchPoth = 1 Then
         MouseMove( $x, $y, 10 )
         MouseClick( "Left" , $x, $y, 10 )

      EndIf
   EndIf
   Sleep 30000
   WEnd
EndFunc
```

I have tried:

```
While 1 = 1
```

Or making a variable that is always true.

Answer (score 0):

You are never calling your function `Start()`. It's not sufficient to just declare it. You have to explicitly call it at least once during your main program flow. The point is, there is no time in your program to wait for a press of the defined HotKey. The function is defined and after this your program just ends because the normal program flow (from the first to the last line) is finished. You need to put another infinite Sleep-Loop outside of your function definition for the program to wait for a HotKey input... ;-) And you probably didn't mean to put the While-Loop inside of your function - or do you want the image to be searched every 30 seconds periodically once you pressed `S`?

```
While True
    Sleep(1) ; this could be much longer, doesn't really matter...
WEnd
```

Comment: As soon as a start the program I want it to start and to keep scanning for the image every 5 seconds and to only stop scanning when I close the program.

Comment: Why do you use a HotKey then? You should only use one to exit the program at the end without the need to click on the tray symbol or kill the process...

Comment: Just delete `Func Start()` and `EndFunc` then.